# += operator overloading in Dart

Tags: dart

I trying make the following overloading inside my class:

```
class Array extends ListBase<double> {
    List<double> l = [];

    List<double> operator +=(List<double> b) {
        var c = Array.length(l.length);
        for(int i = 0; i < l.length; i++) {
          c[i] = this[i] * b[i];
        }
        return c;
      }
}
```

but the Dart compiler show the error message: **the string '+=' ins't a user-definable operator**. Is there some way to make the overloading of the operator `+=` for others classes types?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Overload only `operator +`. Dart reuse operators that have a well known semantic meaning such as `+=`. 
Add `@override` annotation if operator already defined in base class.

Comment: But, how can I do if I already defined the `+` operator for another function?

Comment: If you already have overloaded `operator+`, then I think that `+=` should already work. https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#assignment-operators

Comment: But the problem is: the overloading of the operator + didn't work in the class above, because It extends from ListBase. How can make the + overloading in this case?

Comment: Add ```@override``` annotation:
 ```@override  List<double> operator +(List<double> b) {...```

Comment: Worked for me, thank you. Can you add this override detail in your answer?